# Activate Format Painter with the equivalent effect to double clicking

Tags: vba, excel

I know that ALT+H,F,P activates Format Painter, but this only activates it for your next selection, whereas a double click on Format Painter activates the tool until the user hits ESC key.

I would like Excel 2010 VBA code that activates Format Painter for more than one selection, until I hit ESC. Basically, I am requesting VBA code that activates the double click setting of Format Painter.

Comment: See if this works `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("b3").Copy
 Worksheets("sheet2").Range("g1:g5").PasteSpecial xlFormats` . Other way could be to enable / disable ribbon commands. Enable command example `    m_blnCopyEnabled = Not m_blnCopyEnabled
    m_rbxRibbon.Invalidate`

Comment: @skakkar, your first suggestion is helpful but not exactly how I'd like to accomplish my inquiry because I would need to execute your macro for each range. I would like a macro that activates Format Painter until I cancel Format Painter. That way, I'm able to key around adjacent cells and click on nonadjacent cells applying formatting on simply activating the cell(s). As far as your second suggestion, I would need more detail on how to implement this idea.

Answer (score 0):

I remembered having it in my Code-library. I am also uploading Sample macro file which has 3  Buttons Toggle Copy, Toggle Cut and Toggle Paste. When you press say Toggle Copy Button you will see on ribbon this feature getting enabled or disabled. HTH

Ribbon_xml_macro.xlsm https://www.dropbox.com/s/rrg292652ug137g/Ribbon_xml_macro.xlsm?dl=0

Use this ribbon xml which contains disable commands.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
<commands>
        <!-- Disablae right click menu -->
        <command idMso="Cut" enabled="false"/>
        <command idMso="Copy" enabled="false"/>
        <command idMso="Paste" enabled="false"/>
        <command idMso="PasteMenu" enabled="false"/>
        <command idMso="PasteAsPictureMenu" enabled="false"/>
</commands>
</customUI>
```

Use this ribbon xml which contains enable commands.

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui" onLoad="rxIRibbonUI_onLoad">
<commands>
        <!-- Disablae right click menu -->
        <command idMso="Cut" getEnabled="rxshared_getEnabled"/>
        <command idMso="Copy" getEnabled="rxshared_getEnabled"/>
        <command idMso="Paste" getEnabled="rxshared_getEnabled"/>
        <command idMso="PasteMenu" getEnabled="rxshared_getEnabled"/>
        <command idMso="PasteAsPictureMenu" getEnabled="rxshared_getEnabled"/>
</commands>
</customUI>
```

Code in xlsm standard code module

```
Private m_blnCutEnabled As Boolean
Private m_blnCopyEnabled As Boolean
Private m_blnPasteEnabled As Boolean
Private m_rbxRibbon As IRibbonUI
Sub ToogleCut()

    m_blnCutEnabled = Not m_blnCutEnabled
    m_rbxRibbon.Invalidate

End Sub
Sub ToogleCopy()

    m_blnCopyEnabled = Not m_blnCopyEnabled
    m_rbxRibbon.Invalidate

End Sub
Sub TooglePaste()

    m_blnPasteEnabled = Not m_blnPasteEnabled
    m_rbxRibbon.Invalidate

End Sub

Sub rxIRibbonUI_onLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set m_rbxRibbon = ribbon
End Sub
Sub rxshared_getEnabled(Control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)

    Select Case Control.ID
    Case "Cut"
        returnedVal = m_blnCutEnabled
    Case "Copy"
        returnedVal = m_blnCopyEnabled
    Case "PasteMenu", "Paste", "PasteAsPicture"
        returnedVal = m_blnPasteEnabled
    End Select

End Sub
```